# Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, timeout

I'm running a curl request on an eXist database through php. The dataset is very large, and as a result, the database consistently takes a long amount of time to return an XML response. To fix that, we set up a curl request, with what is supposed to be a long timeout.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers["Content-Length"] = strlen($postString);
$headers["User-Agent"] = "Curl/1.0";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin:');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

However, the curl request consistently ends before the request is completed (<1000 when requested via a browser). Does anyone know if this is the proper way to set timeouts in curl?

Answer (score 432):

See documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` - The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` - The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

also don't forget to enlarge time execution of php script self:

```
set_time_limit(0);// to infinity for example
```

Comment: You don't need `set_time_limit(0);` if the script is running on the console.

Comment: @PedroLobito what you mention is the default config of the php on cli, but it is possible that this may have been modified.

Comment: @cherouvim is obviously correct here (just run `php -d max_execution_time=1  -r 'while(true){$r=1*1;}'` or something to observe in action that the cli does not have a magic 'always unlimited' flag.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito you don't need `set_time_limit(0)` if you are not using it inside a loop.

Comment: CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT = 0 doesn't mean "indefinitely"

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html

"Set to zero to switch to the default built-in connection timeout - 300 seconds."

Answer (score 62):

Hmm, it looks to me like `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` defines the amount of time that any cURL function is allowed to take to execute. I think you should actually be looking at `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` instead, since that tells cURL the maximum amount of time to wait for the connection to complete.

Comment: While the [docs in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) say `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is about how long the function takes, the [underlying curl library docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html) seem to say it's about how long the request takes, which is an interesting distinction - not sure which way to read that!

Comment: I think here is the best interpretation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776129/php-curl-curlopt-connecttimeout-vs-curlopt-timeout

Answer (score 52):

There is a quirk with this that might be relevant for some people...  From the PHP docs comments.

> If you want cURL to timeout in less than one second, you can use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`, although there is a bug/"feature"  on "Unix-like systems" that causes libcurl to timeout immediately if the value is < 1000 ms with the error "cURL Error (28): Timeout was reached".  The explanation for this behavior is:
>
> "If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the transfer will still use full-second resolution for timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second."
>
> What this means to PHP developers is "You can't use this function without testing it first, because you can't tell if libcurl is using the standard system name resolver (but you can be pretty sure it is)"
>
> The problem is that on (Li|U)nix, when libcurl uses the standard name resolver, a SIGALRM is raised during name resolution which libcurl thinks is the timeout alarm.
>
> The solution is to disable signals using CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL.  Here's an example script that requests itself causing a 10-second delay so you can test timeouts:

```
if (!isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    // Client
    $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/test/test_timeout.php?foo=bar');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) {
        echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
    } else {
        echo "Data received: $data\n";
    }
} else {
    // Server
    sleep(10);
    echo "Done.";
}
```

*From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#104597*

Answer (score 34):

Your code sets the timeout to 1000 **seconds**. For milliseconds, use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`.

Answer (score 16):

You will need to make sure about timeouts between you and the file.
In this case PHP and Curl.

To tell Curl to never timeout when a transfer is still active, you need to set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to `0`, instead of `1000`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
```

---

In PHP, again, you must remove time limits or PHP it self (after 30 seconds by default) will kill the script along Curl's request. *This alone should fix your issue*.
In addition, if you require data integrity, you could add a layer of security by using `ignore_user_abort`:

```
# The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.
set_time_limit(0);

# Make sure to keep alive the script when a client disconnect.
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

A client disconnection will interrupt the execution of the script and possibly damaging data,
eg. non-transitional database query, building a config file, ecc., while in your case it would download a partial file... and you might, or not, care about this.

Answering this old question because this thread is at the top on engine searches for `CURL_TIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't run the request from a browser, it will timeout waiting for the server running the CURL request to respond. The browser is probably timing out in 1-2 minutes, the default network timeout.

You need to run it from the command line/terminal.

Comment: +1 -- the timeout is probably external to curl.  You can actually work around the browser timeout by making sure to periodically output something; browsers generally reset their timeout every time they receive more data.  But that's a hack; running via CLI is (almost?) always preferable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP as a fastCGI application then make sure you check the fastCGI timeout settings.
See: [PHP curl put 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053246/php-curl-put-500-error)

Answer (score 0):

Not related, but mind that `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` expects an array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')` ;-)