# Anything wrong with my cURL code (http status of 0)?

Tags: php, curl

Consistently getting a status of 0 even though if I copy and paste the url sent into my browser, I get a json object right back

```
<?php


$mainUrl = "https://api.xxxx.com/?";
$co = "xxxxx";
$pa = "xxxx";
$par = "xxxx";
$part= "xxxx";
$partn = "xxxx";
$us= "xxx";
$fields_string;
$fields = array(
            'co'=>urlencode($co),
            'pa'=>urlencode($pa),
            'par'=>urlencode($par),
            'part'=>urlencode($part),
            'partn'=>urlencode($partn),
            'us'=>urlencode($us)
            );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&' ;}

$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, "&");
$fields_string = "?" . $fields_string;

$url = "https://api.xxxxx.com/" . $fields_string;

$request =  $url; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,'3');
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
print $url;
print $http_status;
print $content; 



?>
```

Comment: just an unrelated side note: PHP has a very handy `http_build_query` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: is `https`, is there any error returned ?

Comment: Yup, just realized that checking the error would be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Realized that I was having SSL issues. Simply set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false. Works.

Comment: If you wish to use SSL, you can add the CURLOPT_CAINFO flag and point to a certificate. Like 'curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, BASE_DIR . '/certs/cacert.pem');'

Comment: @Xoc: +1 from me for pointing out that a secure connection is an option here.

Answer (score 17):

FYI, you can also get a status code of 0 if the curl connection times out before the remote server returns data. In that case you need to set curl time out options to avoid that situation. Just posting this for anyone else having status 0 problems.

Comment: Details on how to set the curl time out are here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066378/243233

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, You MUST run the **curl_exec($ch)** command before you run the **curl_getinfo($ch)** command.

Comment: Perfect! This was the problem for me!

Answer (score 4):

so try this you will get positive results i have added CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false

```
<?php


$mainUrl = "https://api.xxxx.com/?";
$co = "xxxxx";
$pa = "xxxx";
$par = "xxxx";
$part= "xxxx";
$partn = "xxxx";
$us= "xxx";
$fields_string;
$fields = array(
            'co'=>urlencode($co),
            'pa'=>urlencode($pa),
            'par'=>urlencode($par),
            'part'=>urlencode($part),
            'partn'=>urlencode($partn),
            'us'=>urlencode($us)
            );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&' ;}

$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, "&");
$fields_string = "?" . $fields_string;

$url = "https://api.xxxxx.com/" . $fields_string;

$request =  $url; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,'3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);
print $url;
print $http_status;
print $content; 



?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should always set the option CURLOPT_VERBOSE when you are debugging for curl. Your timeout value looks very low.