# cURL to get response from Google Safe Browsing Lookup

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get response using the Google Safe Browsing Lookup API like this:

```
$url ="https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=myappname&apikey=mykey&appver=1.0&pver=3.0&url=".urlencode($myurl);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

I know that my URL is correct since if I dump it and then paste it to the browser I get the expected result (for example 'malware').
So I am assuming it must be something with cURL. I'm working on localhost and extension=php_curl.dll is un-commented in my php.ini, Php version 5.4.4

The html_code is always 0

Comment: What is var_dump($body); returning if you put it after the last line of your code?

Comment: @webbandit the $body is FALSE

Comment: `curl_exec();` - If the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, `FALSE` on failure. Use `var_dump(curl_error($c))` right after `$body = curl_exec($c);` to inspect error.

Comment: @webbandit thanks! The error report is "SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

Answer (score 1):

Simply set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false.

[Anything wrong with my cURL code (http status of 0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570973/anything-wrong-with-my-curl-code-http-status-of-0)

Also check http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1291 , it might help. It is different APIs, but with the same problem anyway.

Comment: I already had CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to false, setting also CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem and its solution is very nicely described here:

http://richardwarrender.com/2007/05/the-secret-to-curl-in-php-on-windows/

Basically if you are not using a standalone version of cURL the chances are that the cURL functions do not include a certificate bundle which was needed in my case since I was trying to connect to **secure** host.

```
$ch = curl_init();
// Apply various settings
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/xampp/ca-bundle.crt"); //path to the CA-bundle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```