# How to detect whether a website is not overloading or not?

Tags: php, curl

I need to find a way to detect whether a website (a joseki end point) is overloaded or not. `http://128.250.202.125:7001/joseki/oracle` is always up, but when I submit a query, sometimes it is idling. (i.e. overloaded, rather than it is down)

My approach so far is to simulate a form submission using curl. if curl_exec return false, I know the website is overloaded.

The major problem is that I am not sure whether website overloading triggers 'FALSE return' or not.
I can log the curl_exec's return using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359100/what-would-cause-curl-to-return-false-when-trying-to-access-a-local-file), but this the website going down.

```
<?php

$is_run = true;
if($is_run) {
    $url = "http://128.250.202.125:7001/joseki/oracle";

    $the_query = "
PREFIX dc:    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX fn:    <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX ouext: <http://oracle.com/semtech/jena-adaptor/ext/user-def-function#>
PREFIX oext:  <http://oracle.com/semtech/jena-adaptor/ext/function#>
PREFIX ORACLE_SEM_FS_NS: <http://oracle.com/semtech#timeout=100,qid=123>
SELECT ?sc ?c
WHERE 
  { ?sc rdfs:subClassOf ?c} 
    ";

    // Simulate form submission.    
  $postdata = http_build_query(array('query' => $the_query));
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $tmp_condi = curl_exec($curl);

    // After I submit a simulated form submission, and http://128.250.202.125:7001/joseki/oracle is
    // not responding (i.g. idling), does it definitely returns FALSE????
  if($tmp_condi === FALSE) {
    die('not responding');  
  }
    else {

    }

  curl_close($curl);
}
```

**Solution**

Able to solve it by adding the following, based on this: [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

Comment: you can use `curl_error($curl)` after curl_exec to see if an error happened.

Comment: @Asenar I already put logging into the code and I am waiting for the site to go down. Have you seen any site which is not responding, and curl_exec returns false?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find a way to detect whether a website is responding or not.
>   My approach so far is to simulate a form submission using curl.

I'd rather do HTTP HEAD request ([see docs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4)) and check return code. You do not need any data returned so no point of sending POST request or fetching response. I'd also set shorten timeout for the request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

if `$http_status` is 200 (OK) then remote end can perhaps be considered live.

Comment: I reworded for my question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even understand what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the website doesnt respond for some time (set in `CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT`) it will trigger an error and `curl_exec()` will return `false`, in fact it will return `false` on any other error either, so your code will not actualy tell if the site is down or not.

Comment: I reworded for my question.