# downloading files from the secure ftp server with R

Tags: r

I need to download files from sftp server and parse them and insert to contents to the database.

I am currently using rCurl as follows:

```
library(RCurl) 
url<-c("sftp://data.ftp.net/incomining.data.txt")
x<-getURL(url, userpwd="<id>:<passwd>")
writeLines(x, incoming.data.txt"))
```

I also looked at download.file and I dont see sftp sufpport in download.file. Has anybody else done similiar work like this? Since I will be getting multiple files, I noticed that rcurl sometimes times out. I like to sftp download  all the files from the sftp server first then process it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the question is "how do I avoid timeouts in rcurl?"

Increase the value of CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.  This is really just the same problem as [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php) .

Edit, from comments below:

```
x<-getURL(url, userpwd="<id>:<passwd>", connecttimeout=60) // 60 seconds, e.g.
```

Comment: do you know where to set the RCurl timeout in R?

Comment: @user1471980 check out `curlOptions()`

Comment: For 60 seconds, http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/philosophy.html suggests appending **connecttimeout=60**, like this: `x<-getURL(url, userpwd="<id>:<passwd>", connecttimeout=60)`