# Download .RData and .csv files from FTP using RCurl (or any other method)

Tags: r, ftp, download, rcurl

I've uploaded a .RData file (created using `save()`) to an ftp server, and I'm trying to use getURL() to download that same file. For all the examples and posts I've read, I can't seem to get this to work.

The .RData file was saved using:

```
save(results, file=RDataFilePath, compress="xz") #save object "results" w/ compression
#RDataFilePath is the location of the results.RData file on my harddrive
```

These data were uploaded using:

```
uploadURL <-"ftp://name:password@host/folder/results.RData" #name the url
ftpUpload(RDataFilePath, to=uploadURL, connecttimeout=120) #upload
```

This is how I try to download results.RData using `getURL`:

```
downloadURL <- "host/folder/results.RData"
load(getURL(downloadURL, userpwd="name:password", connecttimeout=120))
```

which gives the following error:

```
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'ý7zXZ'
```

When I paste the `downloadURL` string into my browser, the .RData file downloads immediately, so I know there isn't a typo.  The error message suggests that the url can't get read b/c of the compression formatting; however, I get a similar error message when I use `save()` w/o compression.

I also get an error message when trying to download a .csv from the FTP:

```
read.csv(getURL(downloadURL1)) #downloadURL1 is similar to downloadURL, but points to the .csv file
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

and then a warning which states `In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file` and then starts listing the contents of the .csv.

I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of the morning, and I feel like I must be missing something really basic. I'm guessing that I need to change some curl option so that it knows what type of file it is going to read. My syntax is probably a bit off, and I'm not using getURL correctly, but I'm not sure what I should be doing.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. My current approach is based on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087209/downloading-files-from-the-secure-ftp-server-with-r)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try breaking it into two steps:  first download the file, then load it.

```
download.file(downloadURL, "temp.rData")
load("temp.rData")
```

or sticking with rCurl you can try:

```
bin = getBinaryURL(downloadURL, ...yourOtherParams...) 
writeBin(bin, "temp.rData")  
load("temp.rData")
```

Comment: This method works for the .csv file (I used `test=getURL( )` and `read.csv(text=test)` Thanks! However, I still get an error when trying to read the .RData file "Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : embedded nul in string: 'ý7zXZ'". When I try download.file, it says that it cannot open the URL.

Comment: Are you on a unix system?  If you have curl setup for command line use you can try something like system("curl ftp://xxxx temp.rData") from within R.  If curl isn't working, maybe "wget" will work?

Comment: I'm on OSX, my colleagues will be on Windows. I don't get very far with download.file, it won't connect to the server.  I've been using the RCurl package.  Using `getBinaryURL()` I can get in the file in binary form, but it's all gibberish and I can't figure out how to convert it. It's class is "raw", and save() then load() again does not convert it back to the original R object (or anything meaningful).

Comment: This worked like a charm! I had just about given up... thank you so much! I searched for a solution to this for 6.5 hrs, and this is what got me there.  I hope that other people trying to solve this problem find your answer :)  It should also be noted that I did not have to pass any other special parameters to getBinaryURL, the defaults worked (except I had to pass my name:pass to `userpwd=').

Answer (score 3):

I spent quite a bit of time on this as well - hoping to use this in a Shiny app so I don't want to write to disk.

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "ftp://F1World@aesius.ca/ALLF1Data.Rda"
userpwd <- "name:password"
bin = getBinaryURL(url, userpwd = userpwd, verbose = TRUE,
                   ftp.use.epsv = TRUE)

load(rawConnection(bin))
```

By Using rawConnection() I was able to avoid the write to disk step as it handled the RAW data type perfectly and avoided the error.
FYI - This is my first post so I hope it's helpful

Comment: This scheme doesn't seem to work for me with a ".RData" file; R comes back with: `the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection`, is this solution solely for a ".Rda" file?