# How to save data generated from user interaction in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I've built an app in shiny which generates data from user interaction. I would like to know the best ways of storing this data for later retrieval.

UPDATE 9/10/2018: This is explained in detail in RStudio webpage:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/share-data.html

Comment: Here's another approach: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the file on:

[1] An FTP server [Download .RData and .csv files from FTP using RCurl (or any other method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833031/download-rdata-and-csv-files-from-ftp-using-rcurl-or-any-other-method)

[2] Amazon s3

[3] Dropbox (rDrop package)