# How to read RData file with R

Tags: r, httr, rdata

How can I read RData with httr? I tried a couple of things but I got error

a)

```
download.file(downloadURL, "temp.rData")
load("temp.rData")
```

b)

```
bin = getBinaryURL(downloadURL, ...yourOtherParams...) 
writeBin(bin, "temp.rData")  
load("temp.rData")
```

from thread [Download .RData and .csv files from FTP using RCurl (or any other method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833031/download-rdata-and-csv-files-from-ftp-using-rcurl-or-any-other-method)

and also using httr

c)

```
  a=GET("https://github.com/tvganesh/yorkrData/blob/master/IPL/IPL-T20-matches/Chennai%20Super%20Kings-Deccan%20Chargers-2008-05-06.RData")
  writeBin(a$content,"aa.RData")
  load("aa.RData")
```

but I get the error

```
 Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
 In addition: Warning message:
  file ‘t.rData’ has magic number '<'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: Try the `mode="wb"` argument to `download.file()` to force binary transfer.  Also consider operating-system level tools:  `ftp`, `scp`, ...

Comment: @Dirk, yes I had used mode="wb". It did not help

Comment: `load(url("https://github.com/tvganesh/yorkrData/raw/master/IPL/IPL-T20-matches/Chennai%20Super%20Kings-Deccan%20Chargers-2008-05-06.RData"))`

Comment: @jojo - I get "Error: the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection"

Comment: @TinniamV.Ganesh Which version of R you are using? I tested with R3.3.1 without any problem. (I get a dataframe `overs` from the RData-file.)

Comment: @jojo - Strange. I am also using R3.3.1. Also tried in another system "get the magic number issue".By the way overs data frame is correct.

Comment: Taking the url to the comments here it breaks. I copied the url from the Download-button of the github-page.

Comment: @jojo - It works!  Your URL has "raw" wheres mine has "blob" With this URL it works You can answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
load(url("https://github.com/tvganesh/yorkrData/raw/master/IPL/IPL-T20-matches/Chennai%20Super%20Kings-Deccan%20Chargers-2008-05-06.RData"))
```

I get a dataframe `overs` from the RData-file.
The url is taken from the Download-button of the github-page to get the raw file.