# Loading ftp directly to R dataframe - how to see the original text?

Tags: r, dataframe, ftp

Is it possible to load ftp files directly to the R workspace without downloading it?
I have 700+ files each around 1.5 Gb and I want to extract approx 0.1 % of the  information from every files and add them into a single dataframe.

I had a look at [Download .RData and .csv files from FTP using RCurl (or any other method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833031/download-rdata-and-csv-files-from-ftp-using-rcurl-or-any-other-method), could not get it to work.

Edit: After some reading, i managed to get the files into R

```
library(httr)
r <- GET("ftp://ftp.ais.dk/ais_data/aisdk_20141001.csv", write_memory())
```

when i try to read the body i use

```
content(r, "text")
```

but the output is gibberish. It might be because of the encoding, but how do i know which encoding the server uses. Any ideas on how to get the original data from the ftp?

Comment: the `curl` pkg and `httr` pkg (which uses the `curl` pkg) can "write to memory" vs disk. Time to read the help pages of those pkgs and experiment, esp since you've provided no code or URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, which is very simple, but works nonetheless:

```
library(data.table)
r <- fread("ftp://ftp.ais.dk/ais_data/aisdk_20141001.csv")
```

[This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/importing-data-into-r-part-two/) blog was helpfull