# PHP Curl - If no response within a certain time, proceed

Tags: php, curl, time, python-idle, abort

I have a network system that checks other sites and displays results. However some of those sites can be slow to respond.

I'd like Curl to wait only a small time before saying "forget this site!" and moving onto the next.

How do you make curl abort an attempt after so much "idle" time?

The reason I did not post any code is because I have no idea where to even start on this feature! **Be kind.** :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate options for the timeout:

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT
Time (in seconds) spent connecting (set to 0 for infinite wait time)

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
Time (in seconds) spent while curl is executing (set to 0 for inifinite wait time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT in the manual. Also, search Stack Overflow before posting - [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

Comment: Half the problem is not knowing the terminology to search for. I searched "abort" and such..."timeout" would have brought me right there but I didn't think of such terminology. **In short I DID just that.**