# php curl script gives nginx 500 error - nothing in nginx error log, nothing in httpd log

Tags: php, nginx

I have a php script which does a few curl requests through proxies.
I keep getting a 500 error after about 30s. I have no idea why as there is nothing in the nginx error log and nothing in the httpd error log.
I have set php timeout to 600s.
I also tried to add this to my script:

```
ini_set('error_log','/var/www/php_errors.txt');
```

so I could get info but nothing there either.

I also added these variables to nginx.conf file:

```
  proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;
```

How can I test to see if my nginx timeout setting is functioning?
Is there an equivalent of php_info for nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Wow after 3 days I finally worked this out.
The 500 timout issue is due to fastCGI timeout setting.

Answered here: [PHP curl put 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053246/php-curl-put-500-error/20931358#20931358)