# PHP curl headers

Tags: php, json, curl, jsonp

I am not very good using PHP and cURL, normally I just make a call with either javascript or C# however I am working with wordpress so C# is not possibly, and I have an apikey with in the call url, so I was wondering if I could have some help with this.  In javascript, the call would be.

```
     var forecastOptions = {
        "cache":  false,
        "dataType":  "jsonp",
        "url":  callSite
    };
    var forecastRequest = $.ajax(forecastOptions);
```

I do it this way for my readability.  I also don't want to turn on the "allow_url_fopen"

**EDIT**

So this is what I have now.

```
    <?php
      $api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
      $latitude = "40.5122";
      $longitude = "-88.9886";
      $API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/';

      $request_url = $API_ENDPOINT .
        $api_key . '/' .
        $latitude . ',' . $longitude;

        $ch = curl_init();

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json'
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($ch);


        $content = json_decode($result, true);

        if(empty($content)){
            print_r("Empty");
        }

    ?>
```

It is telling me that $content is empty.  What am I missing if anything.

Answer (score 2):

Mister Dodd is correct, but the use of JSONP suggests that you were doing a cross-site request. Since PHP generally runs on the server side you won't need to worry about that. You will just need to ensure that the url you use returns JSON. You may want to add headers to your request like this:

```
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Accept: application/json'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

When you execute the request, you can retrieve the response and the HTTP status like this:

```
// Get the result
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Get the status
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close the session
curl_close($ch);

//Parse the JSON
$result_arr = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: I have updated my code, but I am not getting anything from the request.  Am I missing something in my code?  I am trying to pull from the forecast.io api.

Comment: You should try the url you are using from the browser and see if it returns anything.

You should also check the HTTP status from `$httpCode` above.

Comment: I did print_r($httpCode) and it gave me 0. I took the call url and put it in the browser url to be sure that it was the correct url(it was) I then took and pasted that url in place of $request_url.  And I am still getting the same results.

Comment: Your response is probably timing out. You will need to add timeout parameters, which is well explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for documentation on all of PHP's cURL functions. Also, I'm not familiar with cURL in JS, so I'm not sure how to match your options, but all of the cURL options for PHP can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

As an example, It should look something like this:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```