# PHP curl_exec() returning incomplete data

Tags: php, json, curl

```
$url='http://api.cruiseline.com/cruises/7-night-western-caribbean-ft-lauderdale-roundtrip-35052/detail';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result=json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Here is the response of curl_getinfo()

```
array(26) { ["url"]=> string(96) "http://api.cruiseline.com/cruises/7-night-western-caribbean-ft-lauderdale-roundtrip-35052/detail" ["content_type"]=> string(16) "application/json" ["http_code"]=> int(200) ["header_size"]=> int(511) ["request_size"]=> int(127) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(5.11) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.203) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.532) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.532) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(650744) ["speed_download"]=> float(127347) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(1.125) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_ip"]=> string(14) "75.101.141.196" ["primary_port"]=> int(80) ["local_ip"]=> string(13) "192.168.10.15" ["local_port"]=> int(59916) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Above code sometimes sends complete json data and sometimes sends partial data to `$result`. When it sends incomplete data, `json_decode` returns `null`.

There is no issue on server side. When we open http://api.cruiseline.com/cruises/7-night-western-caribbean-ft-lauderdale-roundtrip-35052/detail in browser, it sends complete response all the time.

Please help and let me know what is the problem and how I can fix that.

Comment: Check out the curl_getinfo($ch) before closing it... And post it, might help us.

Comment: Try adjusting the [timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

Comment: I just submitted the response from curl_getinfo()

Comment: @DarkBee curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400) and also used curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5) but no difference.

Comment: it is possible that this is caused due to non-utf8 characters? Try to utf8 encode your $result `$result= utf8_encode($result);` and then json_decode() it

Comment: I directly printed curl_exec() but due to issue it was not printing complete response data. however issue seems fixed from answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

to your `cURL` setup. This made your code workable for me.

Comment: It seems working now. Can you please explain how CURLOPT_ENCODING works?

Comment: I think, that there was something wrong with encoding of received data. Per manual: if an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent. That's why now the data is decoded correctly.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But for same data it was working some time and sometimes it was giving an error.

Comment: Cause that "some data" was encoded correctly. It is hard to predict, what data will be sent, that's why for such cases it is useful to enable automatic encoding.

Comment: Thank you so much.