# How can I reproduce an HTTP 408 timeout error for testing?

Tags: php, http, curl, error-handling, error-code

As part of the registration for my Drupal 7 site I require the user to enter a valid phone number. Rather than doing only simple validation, I use the Numverify.com API to verify the format of the number on a per country basis and obtain extra information. This is done via a curl request which returns a json object.

The other day the API was unreachable for several hours and due to my lack of foresight, users were unable to register until I circumvented the API request.

To prevent this in the future, I need to be able to properly handle error codes such as 408. Would anybody be able to tell me how I can replicate a timeout request, locally or otherwise, for testing purposes please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hanshenrik I managed to combine his answer with my own research.

To get a 408 (or any other response) for testing and handling purposes using curl, I made a PHP file containing `http_response_code(408);` then from my index.php file, I initiated curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "timeout.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

echo $httpcode;
```

The important line is the `curl_get_info` section that will return the http response code from the previous page.I can then handle this code appropriately in my index.php file.

I don't really know if this is the most efficient way to do this, so if anyone can improve my answer, please feel free.

In the meantime, I hope this helps someone else out there!

Answer (score 3):

make a php page with the content: `<?php http_response_code(408);` and fetch that with curl.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for although it took me a while to figure out how to use it for what I wanted. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also simulate slow network with last versions of Firefox Development Edition. But I'm not sure how much you can control the latency. See this [article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/11/new-responsive-design-mode-rdm-lands-in-firefox-dev-tools/) for more information about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about D7 specifically, but I know that you can GuzzleHttp to try-catch RequestException's which includes 400 and 500 series response codes.  You can additionally set a timeout, so that if it doesn't respond within X seconds, then just continue.  You can also supply the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT options to your cURL object, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066378/7118098