# PHP: Call URL with setting timeout?

Tags: php, url, curl, fopen

I want to call a certain URL in my PHP script and if I do not get a response after 10s, the script should just continue. Does anyone knows how I can do that?

I only found two ways. One is `fopen()`, which determinates my script if it doesn't get a return and `curl` which is just calling the URL without waiting/getting response?

But how can I say, try to get the content of the URL and if you do not get anything after 10s then continue and ignore the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If timeout is occurred - $response variable has boolean 'false' value.