# php - Jump to next member of foreach if takes to long time to execute

Tags: php, foreach, php-curl

I have this code for checking urls:

```
function check_url($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $headers['http_code'];
}
```

And my arrays:

```
$urls = array(1,2,3,"AAAA",4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

(For example AAAA takes 200ms and others takes 4s)

And this is my loop

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    check_url("http://www.example.com/" . $url);
}
```

Question is how can I set a timeout for each member?
I mean, If checking member takes more than 2ms, jump to next member.

Comment: When you say "jump to next member", do you want to actually skip/cancel the one that is taking a long time? Or are you wanting to keep that active while moving on to the next one?

Comment: maybe set `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` or `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

Comment: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` or `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` for max execution time. Your loop is taking long because curl is waiting for a response.

Comment: You can just set 2 seconds timeout for Curl inside your `check_url` function . See  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php) for details

Comment: Yes, that's the situation, Patrick.

Comment: @arazgholami _which_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP version newer, than 5.2.3, you can use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` curl option to do that.

So, in essence:

```php
<?php
function check_url($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return empty($headers['http_code']) ? 0 : $headers['http_code'];
}

$urls = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.tatawilkolak.pl');

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo check_url($url) . " ";
}
?>
```

If URL timeout'ed, returned HTTP code will be 0. In my code I have set 200ms as a timeout, but you can play with this number.