# php curl post huge string not being sent

Tags: php, curl

Got this cURL php post request to a remote server but it's not working properly:

```
#$long_value equals a 1400000 bytes string

$array = array(
    'value' => 1,
    'long_value' => $long_value,
);

$array = http_build_query($array);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain_name.com/url/to/script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The point is that it's not giving me any errors (both error_log and `curl_error($ch)`). It's just that it exceeds the maximum time limit (30 seconds) and if I set this time limit to 300 still same result.

I'm working with PHP7 and `post_max_size` is 8MB so my questions are:

**How can I fix this problem?**

**And is it related with the length of the string passed as `$long_value`?**

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //no limit

Comment: On which server did you check errors, and change the time limit ?

Comment: server that make the curl post request @Syscall

Comment: Which time limit did you change? `max_execution_time` doesn't affect the time for stream operations, it's Curl's timeout you'd need to modify. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php

Comment: I was changing `max_execution_time`. Thanks for your reply! I'll try that later and comment results :) @iainn

Comment: @iainn just tried and still not workin :/ keeps on giving me Maximum time limit exceeded...