# curl exec 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, curl

My curl PHP code:

```
$url = "";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If `$url` is, for example, `https://www.google.com` then all is OK.
But if `$url` is, for example, `https://www.twitch.tv` I cannot get answer, just getting:

> 504 error

What can be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

Comment: Nope. Problem: do not conecting to several sites but to others connects.

Comment: They might use some kind of user agent sniffing to deny (never respond) requests coming from `curl` and similar tools. You can try using a fake user agent header, and possibly add some other headers as well to get around this. In the chrome devtools network panel, you can right click a request and choose `copy as curl` to get a curl command which includes the same headers that chrome itself used for that request. There might be a similar feature in other browsers as well.

Comment: I tried to use Discord Oauth that is why I'm trying to understand this. Discord Oauth shouldn't deny requests! So I don't think that your advice will help me.
Update: Did not helped.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the redirection to the https site. Try using the url https://www.twitch.tv.

Comment: That is how I wrote it in URL. Nothing changed.
Added CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT but still cannot understand why it cannot read it for about 10 seconds:
Resolving timed out after 10519 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

It could your ip is Blacklisted  try to use proxy and set SSL_VERIFYPEER to false :

```
$url = "https://www.twitch.tv";
$proxy='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx';
        $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$answer = curl_exec($ch);

print $answer;
```

Comment: I will try. One stupid question: where to get proxy?

Comment: Still do not work.
Connection timed out after 20000 milliseconds. Any others ideas?

Comment: is this link https://www.twitch.tv give u timeout or  another one cuz it working for me