# Timeout error does not match what is set in php.ini

Tags: php, timeout

I used facebook debugger to check my server's image. [Here is the facebook debugger.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

But, I received an error of "Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 444276 out of 524288 bytes received".

[image]

**My server timeout setting**

Here are the settings (php 7 and php 5.6) in **Cpanel**

[image]

[image]

Here is the setting using **ssh** to find php.ini

[image]

Then `vim /etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini`

[image]

Wondering why the error says timeout is 10sec. Any suggestions?

Comment: Max execution time is for the PHP script as a whole.  It has no effect on CURL timeout (other than the case where CURL's timeout is longer than max execution time)  I'd suggest you read PHP's CURL documentation to determine how to configure CURL's timeout.

Comment: PHP's CURL uses the php.ini setting default_socket_timeout. The default value is 60, the unit is seconds.

Comment: @nforced just checked all default_socket_timeout  in php.int. All are 60. Wondering why facebook returns an error saying 10 sec?

Comment: @GordonM But the curl timeout should be on Facebook side as I only provide an url for them to fetch an image? I'm a newbie in server development. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Where do you see this error? In your error_logs or on the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ url? @PakHoCheung

Comment: @PakHoCheung Depends on which is longer.  If Facebook's timeout is shorter than the one you specify in CURL then Facebook should trigger a timeout (probably with a HTTP error code).  If CURL's timeout is shorter then it should give up and disconnect before Facebook times out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php may be more helpful.

Comment: @nforced I attached a screenshot of the error from Facebook.

Comment: @GordonM But I don't need write any code. I only need to provide a url. So, I guess the timeout should be completely based on Facebook's timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The reason comes from slow connection.

Solutions:

1. upgrade your server
2. compress your image
3. increase timeout