# PHP Script - Track overall script execution time (curl)

Tags: php, curl, time

My problem is that I want to kill the script after 58 seconds. But `max_execution_time` just tracks the time of the script execution itself, not my curl call. I could get the time in the beginning of the script and the calculate the time, but I can't do that while my curl is executing. Is there any solution that fit my needs? I don't want to start another thread that tracks the time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS , 58000);`

Comment: I ve already set those options, the problem is im doing up to 9 curl calls and each has a set timeout of 10s, thats why i need the overall time and if needed kill the process while curl is running

Comment: i could check the time after every call but this would have a tolerance of +-10 seconds.

Comment: and i don't really want to use the pthread package, because i want the script to stay protable