# If page load time takes too long

Tags: php, curl, page-load-time

I have a curl script that I would like to wrap in an if condition to proceed anyway if the page isnt loading.  Is it possible to check page load time > if taking too long > proceed anyway?

```
if(pageLoad != TooMuchTime {
  //Curl script to some url
} else {
  //Took to long to get a responce
}
```

The reason I do this is because I use a curl request as part of an install script (to track installs) the curl call is to a php file which inserts data to the database.  If for any reason (network congestion, site down, ect.) the page doesn't load I want the user to still be able to install the product.

Comment: you can use [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), but if the page loaded why does it matter how long it took? curl has options to timeout, set it to *TooMuchTime* and handle the error.. else our need make 2 requests which is not ideal

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php is a good thread to look at?

Comment: Curl has options that control a variety of timeouts. Set the ones you're interested in and handle the error.

Comment: I updated the OP to include how I use this, and why I want such a feature.  Maybe then someone would have an alternative solution for me.

Comment: Thank you @user3783243 that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl offers options to achieve the desired action, There is no need for if conditions.

`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` - The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` - The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```